# How to add a subview in storyboard?

Tags: ios7, uiview, uistoryboard

I my ios app has develped using storyboard. Now I want to add a subview to one of this viewcontroller, in storyboard and when click on a cell this sub view should be come to top. How to add this `UIView`from the interface builder without creating that view programmatically

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried?? you can have UIView of size of your UIViewController. when click on cell it will come to top. when you want remove from superview do removefromsuperview

Comment: I dragged a UIView to one of the UIViewcontroller in storyboard,, then I declared an IBOutlet and that view linked to that outlet. But I want to edit that new view. But view is not visible.

Comment: Onclick of cell make sure you have done this subview.hidden = NO; For more help put either photo or code

Comment: may be you have done some other mistake i have tried it is working

Comment: Im doing this using story board. so I want to know If I add an uiView as a outlet to where should I put that view

Comment: [see this..](http://screencast.com/t/LoL01myc)

Answer (score 0):

**1 Just go to top bar 
2 go to editor 
3 in editor click embed in
4 then select view 
5 after that next view will be add in your storyboard .**